# How to generate the .htpasswd with MD5 encryption with ANT?

Tags: .htaccess, ant, ftp, md5, .htpasswd

I'm programming a ant task whitch create folders on a FTP linux based server, and i would like to make it generate the .htaccess file and the .htpasswd file.

I need to write passwords in the .htpasswd with the MD5 encryption (or other encryption methods), how i can do that ?

Thanks all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call an external executable from your ant file - although that means that it will need to have access to that executable. This may do the trick:

```
<target name="update-htpasswd">
  <exec executable="/usr/bin/htpasswd">
    <arg value="-bm"/>
    <arg value="${passwordfile}"/>
    <arg value="${username}"/>
    <arg value="${plain-password}"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

Guaranteed correct format. Otherwise, you can write your own ant task and call it. Java has built-in MD5 libraries, so you would only have to generate the correct password line in java and append it to the password file. That would be more portable.